# Interpreting K-mean Clusters in R

Tags: r, clustering

I was looking for some assistance in interpreting these two plots. I am using this dataset https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Mo0tFO_aYKYAyI4iCv3vudYmCM5ejK5z/view.

I am not entirely sure what the difference between the elbow and silhouette plot is and how to make an interpretation of the plots.

These are my codes for the clusters:

```
set.seed(1)
options(scipen = 999)
fviz_nbclust(Mall_Customers[, 4:5], kmeans, method = "wss")
fviz_nbclust(Mall_Customers[, 4:5], kmeans, method = "silhouette")
```

I will also include screenshots of them. I just need 2-3 sentences but I am not sure how to interpret these :(

[image: Elbow plot]

[image: Silhouette plot]

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "interpreting 2 clusters"?  Did you perhaps mean to ask about interpreting these *plots?*  If so, please see [our related posts](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=cluster+silhouette), because they probably answer your question.

Comment: @whuber I'm sorry- yes I meant to interpret these plots. I am just not sure what the difference is between the elbow and silhouette plot. I wanted some assistance on how to interpret these two plots

Comment: Have you explored our posts that discuss the two plots?  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=k+means+elbow+silhouette.